# length of keys in a map in Terraform - odd output

Tags: terraform

Given:

```
variable "foo" {
  type = map
  default = {
    lorem = "ipsum"
    dolor = "sit"
  }
}
```

then, in Terraform console, why does
`[for k, v in var.foo : length(k) ]`
give:

```
[
  4,
  5,
]
```

Comment: You would want to output the key with `[for k, v in var.foo: k]`  in terraform console. In this way you can see if the variable `foo` is what you want it to be or it is overwritten by something from `.tfvars`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really odd result.  When I run the exact same thing locally, I get the expected result:

```
> [for k, v in var.foo : length(k) ]
[
  5,
  5,
]
```

Do you have a value set for "foo" in a `*.auto.tfvars` file somewhere?  How about an environment variable called `TF_VAR_foo`?  My best guess is that there is a different variable defined somewhere called "foo" that is overwriting the `default` value specified in the variable declaration.